# Passing a value from one user control to other

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I have a userControl in which I load three different user control as Left,right and middle panel.
My middle panel user control have 3 more user control loaded on it
I want to pass a value from my middle panel user control to right panel user control on click of a link button.

Can please any one guide how to do so.?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method on the user control you need to pass data to.
Then you can call that method from the container and pass in the value.

Another approach is to put the value in session or viewstate.

Comment: No, I dont want to use session or viewstate. Can you give a small example how to call the function from the container.?

Answer (score 0):

Using Session or cookie this is easy way to pass value one control to another control or one page to another page